# Does the centroid of a tetrahedron divide the height in two equal parts?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to calculate a/r ratio for a diamond cubic crystalline structure, but I cannot remember the relationship between the two parts of the height of tetrahedron, which are divided by the centroid.

Comment: Hint: in vector terms the centroid is $\frac14(a+b+c+d)$ where $a$ etc. are the position vectors of the vertices.

Comment: So it divides the height in a 3:1 ratio? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Yes, it does! It's nearer the face than the vertex opposite it. There's more of the tetrahedron nearer the face than the opposite vertex!

Comment: Intuitively NOT. A tetrahedron from the centre to the vertex  is lighter  than the part from the centre of the height to the base. Centroid is the centre of gravity if the tetrahedron is homogeneous...

Comment: @Raffaele I think that the critallographic context of the OP refers to the case where the weights are placed on the vertices.

Comment: Your memory may be aided by noticing that the relationship is part of a pattern across all $d$-dimensional "simplices". $1:1$ in $1$ dimension (segment); $2:1$ in $2$ dimensions (triangle); $3:1$ in $3$ dimensions (tetrahedron); $4:1$, $5:1$, $6:1$, etc, etc, etc, $d:1$ in $d$ dimensions. Of course, that's because, in general, the vector form of the centroid is always $1/(d+1)$-times the sum of the position vectors of the vertices.